# Should site icons be generic black when accessed through the left drop-down?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I noticed that when I am on the generic Stack Exchange page, the one that is linked to by clicking the button furthest left on the top bar, and then I click on that button again to access the drop-down.

The icons for established SE sites are showing up as a generic black icon with lettering. This is in contrast to the dropdown on the farthest right of the top bar, which displays the site icons for each site.

Perhaps this is status-by-design, but it seems to me that the two dropdowns should have consistent icon usage to avoid confusion.

Here are screenshots of both dropdowns, first the one from the top left button that shows the black icons, and then the top right button that shows the normal site icons.

**Black lettering icons:**

[image]

**Normal icons that I'm used to:**

[image]

Comment: Did you do a hard refresh of the page? (ctrl + f5 on most Windows browsers).

Comment: @Oded You're right, that does fix it.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Oded this issue keeps appearing. few minutes back, I saw the stack apps icon for Stack Exchange and SE icon for MSE in the drop down on SE home page

Comment: And a hard refresh doesn't fix it? It could be a cached version on a proxy somewhere between you and us. I can't repro.

Comment: yes. I hard refreshed to check whether it is reprod or not and it's gone. But it appeared after a refresh. I were on the home page and everything is normal, then a refresh broke the things. a hard refresh cleared it. quiet unusual.

Comment: @Oded just fyi, it happened again https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9hRH.png just now